# Mental patient or lunatic patient

Tags: nouns, adjectives

> Torture and trauma has made her a *mental* patient
>
> A) no improvement
> B) lunatic
> C) mania
> D) mad

I am confused in lunatic and mental. Lunatic was the answer given in the book but i find mental to be correct.
What should be correct use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the sentence correctly? Look again, and  then tell us the name of the text book. If possible supply a link.

Comment: Actually it's not any standard book. It was just a exam question answer may be incorrect or there may be misprint.

Comment: Or maybe you misremembered the sentence. The sentence is ungrammatical in British English (and in American English) whichever word is chosen.

Comment: adjective

adjective: lunatic

1.

mentally ill (not in technical use).

"a ward of lunatic old ladies"

extremely foolish or eccentric.

"he would be asked to acquiesce in some lunatic scheme"

Comment: I didn't say "lunatic" is wrong, I said the sentence is ungrammatical. Is this question from a website, did you find the example here: http://www.englishaliens.com/ssc/topic/ssc-cgl-tier-i-ii/sentence-improvement/19

Comment: This is what i found in google translator. Here lunatic is referred to mentally ill. what do you think on this?

Comment: I would not use this website ever,  questions 1, 2 and 4 are ungrammatical whichever solution you choose. For example "*She is very eccentric woman.*" is ungrammatical, an article is missing, it should be "She is ***a*** very eccentric woman" and yet none of the options offer this solution. Use the website, if you must, to help improve your vocabulary but be wary of their proposed sentences.

Comment: I am voting to close this question for several reasons: 1. lack of basic research (the OP didn't check a dictionary before posting his question) 2. Failure to mention that the question was not from a book, where one hopes the contents are proofread, but from a website. 3. The exam question is ungrammatical.

Comment: It wasn't lack of research. These are the question asked in exam and same are given on website..these are also available in local author's book.

Comment: The sentence is bogus to start with.  And "lunatic" is pejorative in the sense, and should not be used in even semi-formal work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: Yes, it is lack of research on your part. You failed to look up the terms in any dictionary before posting what is an off-topic question. *Why* did you think "mental" was correct? Where is your research? Where did you look up the term "mental"? Please, next time, do some basic elementary research, include your findings, thoughts and explain why you are confused in the question. And add the necessary links, it took me seconds to find the site when I understood the question was not from a textbook.

Comment: Ohk.my bad. thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: But to be honest this question is asked in exam for selection in various posts under govt of India. And we have to choose best possible option even if question is incorrect. In rare cases question is eliminated if it makes no sense. And this question was not one of them. So i have to find best possible option because everywhere including books and online platforms lunatic was the answer given. Which i myself thought is not a right word to use. That's why i asked it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exam question is ungrammatical because the article "a" is missing. A grammatically correct form would be:

> "Torture and trauma drove her insane"
>   or
>   "Torture and trauma made/turned her into **a lunatic**"
>   or
>   Torture and trauma made her **mentally** ill

Something either makes a person *lunatic* (adj.), i.e. mad (BrEng), or crazy (AmEng) or a person is
"**a** lunatic" (noun).

### [lunatic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lunatic?s=t)

> **noun**
>   1.(no longer in technical use; now considered offensive) an insane person.
>   **adjective**
>   4. (no longer in technical use; now considered offensive) insane.

The second solution is quite derisive and would never be used in a serious or medical context.

Answer (score 1):

'Lunatic' was an old word for a person with a mental illness (because the condition was thought to be affected by the moon). It should *never* be used now in referring to a genuine mental patient, though it (or the abbreviation 'loony') might be used jokingly about someone with strange ideas or behaviour.

Comment: Must be too much alcohol and turkey leftovers in my system but are you saying that `made her lunatic patient` is the correct answer to the exercise or have you conveniently skirted the issue?

Comment: @Mari-LouA  The questioner said they were confused between 'lunatic' and 'mental', so I was explaining the modern usage of the former.